# Installing nvm via cURL hangs

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, nvm

When I use

```
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
```

to install Node Version Manager via OSX (version 10.13.6) terminal, I get this far and then the terminal hangs:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 13226  100 13226    0     0  10275      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 10284
=> Downloading nvm from git to '/Users/interwebjill/.nvm'
=> Cloning into '/Users/interwebjill/.nvm'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 278, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (278/278), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (249/249), done.
remote: Total 278 (delta 33), reused 93 (delta 16), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (278/278), 142.36 KiB | 1.80 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (33/33), done.
```

Why might that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was a result of an update to my anti-virus software. When I disabled this software, the installation went through.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `--verbose` to report more info to the command line.

So the command will be:

```
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash --verbose
```

If you have the same issue try to run this command: `nvm -v`; maybe you already installed it.

Answer (score 0):

My issue for hanging at `curl` or `nvm install` was my vpn, coming off that fixed it.